# How mention a group of teams in a flow of power automate?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I create a group for question in Microsoft teams, the name for this group is "Information Comunity".  In this group, I put a Microsoft forms to capture the question.

Then, I create a Flow with Microsoft power Automate.  This flow send send a message in "information Comunity" group, like this

[image]

I need to mention a other group in this message, the name of the other group is "Gerencia de information", this group will answer the question.  But  I don´t know how to capture the name of thisgroup or how  i get the id of the other group.

Can you help me please.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1 The Flow will use a manual trigger.
[image]

2.After that the Flow initializes three variables as below:
[image]

3.First make sure that you invoke the HTTP request action connection using `https://graph.microsoft.com` as the Base Resource URL and Azure AD Resource URI values like in the screenshot below:
[image]

4.Then invoke the HTTP request

[image]

Body of the request:

```
{
    "body": {
    "content": "This is Flow mention channel test, <at id=\"0\">RA Experts</at>",
    "contentType": "html"
            },
    "mentions": [
                {
                "id": 0,
                "mentionText": "RA Experts",
                "mentioned": {
                                "conversation": {
                                                    "id": "19:ac7b9c53a099498f9e08679e58f1f7fc@thread.tacv2",
                                                    "displayName": "RA Experts",
                                                    "conversationIdentityType": "channel"
                                                }
                            }
                }
                ]
}
```

5. Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Prasad-MSF.  First of all, thank you for answering my question.
It's very clear what you recommend to me but I can't invoke the HTTP request action, because this is a premium service.  Any other suggestion that allows me to make the mention.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other way via Power Automate. In order to run this API query, you will have to opt for those licenses.